# issues installing caret package

Tags: r, r-caret

I run into some problem while installing R package. I am using R studio in ubuntu.
Here is the problem

```
ERROR: dependency ‘plyr’ is not available for package ‘scales’
* removing ‘/home/nilmadhab/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.0/scales’
Warning in install.packages :
installation of package ‘scales’ had non-zero exit status
ERROR: dependency ‘plyr’ is not available for package ‘reshape2’
* removing ‘/home/nilmadhab/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu- library/3.0/reshape2’
Warning in install.packages :
installation of package ‘reshape2’ had non-zero exit status
ERROR: dependencies ‘plyr’, ‘reshape2’, ‘scales’ are not available for package ‘ggplot2’
* removing ‘/home/nilmadhab/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.0/ggplot2’
Warning in install.packages :
installation of package ‘ggplot2’ had non-zero exit status
ERROR: dependencies ‘ggplot2’, ‘car’, ‘reshape2’, ‘plyr’ are not available for package ‘caret’
* removing ‘/home/nilmadhab/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.0/caret’
Warning in install.packages :
installation of package ‘caret’ had non-zero exit status
```

Comment: have you checked http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25721884/how-should-i-deal-with-package-xxx-is-not-available-for-r-version-x-y-z-wa yet ?

Answer (score 3):

You are using a version of `R` that is more than two years old (version 3.0). Most modern packages require a more recent version. The latest release of `R` is version 3.2.2.

I would suggest that you update your `R` version and try again. A detailed description on how to update `R` on ubuntu is given [here](https://cran.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu/#installation).

```
> tail(rversions::r_versions(),15)
#   version                        date
#82  2.15.0 2012-03-30T07:16:05.708046Z
#83  2.15.1 2012-06-22T07:09:44.415136Z
#84  2.15.2 2012-10-26T07:11:16.605580Z
#85  2.15.3 2013-03-01T08:28:29.088755Z
#86   3.0.0 2013-04-03T07:12:36.801147Z
#87   3.0.1 2013-05-16T07:11:33.885209Z
#88   3.0.2 2013-09-25T07:11:09.016418Z
#89   3.0.3 2014-03-06T08:12:33.995105Z
#90   3.1.0 2014-04-10T07:11:10.831155Z
#91   3.1.1 2014-07-10T07:11:09.316022Z
#92   3.1.2 2014-10-31T08:11:32.082768Z
#93   3.1.3 2015-03-09T08:12:20.229070Z
#94   3.2.0 2015-04-16T07:13:33.144514Z
#95   3.2.1 2015-06-18T07:15:04.589869Z
#96   3.2.2 2015-08-14T07:13:18.272871Z
```